# Получение списка регионов России

Tags: java, html, парсер, кладр

Есть задача по получению актуального списка регионов, городов и соответствующих кодов регионов и городов.
Нашел один сайт: https://kladr-rf.ru/

1. Как я смогу вытащить данные с него, кроме того, что писать парсер и парсить страницы каждого из регионов (пример: https://kladr-rf.ru/01/). Вытаскивая последовательно название региона, код и т.д.
2. Может кто-то получал данные о регионах и есть какое-то открытое API?

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть например в json вот [список](https://gist.github.com/gorborukov/0722a93c35dfba96337b).

Если нужно подробная информация советую использовать [dadata](https://dadata.ru/opendata/). У них все в красивом виде.

Также можно использовать API от https://nominatim.org/

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам за ответ!
С большим уважением отношусь к GitHub, но не понимаю, почему ссылка с https://dadata.ru/opendata/ ведет именно на этот портал. 
Хотелось бы получать данные с версиями обновлений и, желательно,  с государственных источников. Как ни странно, данные регионов частенько обновляются и хотелось бы получать актуальную информацию.

Comment: @LeilaBoord почта России использует dadata.

Comment: Жаль, что в dadata нет конретно списка регионов, а только более детальная информация по каждому населенному пункту.
Мне именно список регионов важен для получения

Comment: @LeilaBoord у них список регионов, у них все есть.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я могу найти в dadata.ru/opendata список регионов, не переходя по ссылке на GitHub (https://github.com/hflabs/region)?
API от https://nominatim.org/ не имеет запросов на получение списка регионов.

Comment: @LeilaBoord https://github.com/hflabs/region/blob/master/region.csv пример